# Проблема с WCF RIA services

Tags: wcf, silverlight

Есть один старый проект, я его время от времени сопровождаю.

Недавно возникла потребность получить данные с базы немного в расширенном варианте. Данные из базы берутся через RIA сервисы, которые просто подключены в одном из концевых проектов через WCF RIA Services link, поэтому самого проекта в IIS нет. Под студией все работает нормально, а вот когда заливаю xap файл на IIS, даже локальный, то данные берутся из базы в том виде который был описан до моих изменений.

в `*.g.cs` файл в проекте где подключены сервисы функцию вызывается уже с измененными параметрами, но результат получается старый.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что у Вас где лежит, но судя по всему Вам нужно обновить ссылки на сервисы в проекте, чтобы обновились контракты

Comment: Ссылка настроена внутри проекта, в его свойствах, по локиге при сборки проекта сервиса, сразу идет обновление

Comment: при сборке проекта ссылка не обновляется автоматически

Comment: вот тут описан механизм каким у меня в проекте подключен сервис http://rsdn.ru/article/net/WCFRIA.xml#EEH

Comment: Проблема решена, забыл что надо еще файл сервисов копирнуть
Спасибо за советы